# googlemap handle event in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

i tried Google-Maps-for-Rails 
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails
and it works well!

I have a question, do you know if it possibile to set an event listener on the map?

I need to get lat and long by clicking on the map and set a marker in that position.
Thanks for your support

Comment: your question led to an improvement of the gem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given you have v0.7.2 or more, just add the following in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function gmaps4rails_callback() {
   google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.map, 'click', function(object){ var position_clicked = object.latLng;});
}
</script>
```

Of course, you then have to create the marker itself.

Sidenote:

All object part of the map are accessible and wrapped in Gmaps4Rails. Have a look at `gmaps4rails.js` I tried to make it clearest possible.

Comment: I added this $(document).ready(function() {

google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.map, 'click', function(object){ var position_clicked = object.latLng; alert(position_clicked);});
}); in my application.js but i get this error "a is null" into firebug console

Comment: didnt worked for me. Cant hook click events from map. I followed standart instructions to build gmaps4rails. Is there any example to see this working?

Comment: @Çağdaş: replace `Gmaps4Rails.map` with `Gmaps.map.serviceObject`

Comment: great consider upvoting if it's useful :)